# Is there a replacement for mdbtools?

Tags: ms-access, mdbtools

I'm using mdbtools' SQL functionality to connect to an `.mdb` file on linux. Mdbtools is still beta and hasn't been updated since 2007, many features like sufficient SQL support aren't available yet.

Features I need:

- SQL, either with python bindings or through ODBC.
- `AS` statement in SQL operations.
- `JOIN` if possible.
- Runs on non-windows.
- Sub-selects would be really handy.
- Write support is *not* necessary.

Is there a replacement for it that is actively being developed?

Comment: Highly unlikely.  I've never seen any such although I don't know everything about Access.  Also write support is highly, highly complex and likely as big a task as everything they've done so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read an Access database in Python on non-Windows platform (Linux or Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25596737/2144390)

Answer (score 7):

MDBtools is again an active project, hosted on github:

```
https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools
```

It appears to be 'official', in that the github account hosting the repository was registered by the original author of mdbtools, Brian Bruns.

He is accepting patches, there is an active-ish issue queue, etc.

Comment: 2020 update: the upstream repo is dead and hasn't seen any recent activity. A maintained fork with many fixes and improvements is available at https://github.com/evanmiller/mdbtools

Answer (score 3):

You could use this http://code.google.com/p/mdb-sqlite/ tool to convert the files to SQLite and use your favourite script language to access it.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question indicating that a different data store is an option. -1

Comment: @ David: Only as a last option if it isn't possible otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I recently came across that maybe of some use.  [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) is a pure Java library for reading from and writing to MS Access databases.

Answer (score -2):

There is an ODBC Driver for Linux that can read ms-access.
http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html

and it costs some money.

Comment: Have you used it or did you just find it in a Google search? Or do you work for EasySoft?