# Easiest option to query mdb (ms access) file using smb in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ms-access, go, database-connection

In my workplace the attendance (fingerprint) device uses `.mdb` file (that stored on Windows PC), and I have a smb account to the network share to that computer `smb://10.7.7.x/tas/`, inside the share folder contains 3 files:

```
 HITFPTA.ldb
 HITFPTA.mdb ==> this one
 HITFPTA_History.mdb
```

What are the easiest option to able to query (in real time) from that file, since our server that should do the query uses Linux (`ArchLinux`)? (if possible using `Go` programming language)

Comment: Your server is Linux, but what about the machine(s) from which you will be querying the .mdb database? Are they Windows machines, something else, or a mix?

Comment: the `.mdb` is in Windows, the server is Linux, the client would be mix of both

Comment: I need to access it (read and duplicate the data from the `.mdb` into our database in server, so it would be easier to produce the required report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For read-only access to a "live" .mdb database from a mix of Windows and non-Windows clients I would recommend using Java and the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)). If you're not keen on writing Java code but have some familiarity with Python then you could use Jython as described in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614063/2144390).

(Jackcess, the data-access layer used by UCanAccess, does not use the Access Database Engine and is not intended to make updates to a live multi-user database. However, it should be able to read the database without incident. For reporting purposes it might be prudent to take a copy of the .mdb file and run the reports against that. Or, stick with Windows clients and use ODBC.)