# python: how to connect to oracle database using jdbc

Tags: python, oracle, jdbc, classpath, jython

Could you please enlighten me on how to connect to an Oracle instance using Python/Jython ?

After installing fully Jython, the Oracle website (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/mastering-oracle-python-providers-1395759.html) suggests to :
*All you need to provide is to make sure ojdbc6.jar is in the CLASSPATH or JYTHONPATH so that the connection driver could be resolved.*

I read that when using the *-jar* option ignores the CLASSPATH environment variable.
So I did like :

```
java -classpath /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar  -jar jython.jar

from java.sql import DriverManager
db_connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521/P1FNTPE", "xxx", "xxx")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521/P1FNTPE
```

Could you please help/advise me on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25614063/2144390) about setting up Jython for JDBC on *nix. You would need to have `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar` in your CLASSPATH (instead of the JARs I mention for UCanAccess). Note that it uses `from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC`. Note also that invoking Jython is done with a `jython` command, not `java -jar jython.jar` (at least that's how it worked for me).

Comment: Thanks Gord. I would need a bit of extra help if possible.

Comment: UCanAccess, i guess is not needed because is not about the MS Access DB

Comment: could you please explain how to call jython and update CLASSPATH ?

Comment: am calling Jython like this now : ./jython but still not changed to the better

Comment: See if the instructions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) help you out. In my case all I did was add the CLASSPATH declaration and `export` command to my .bashrc file.

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7
.0.55.x86_64/jre/bin

Comment: Adding the jar location to the PATH environment variable won't help. CLASSPATH is where it needs to go.

Comment: jython.jar is under /home_ldap/nskalis/jython directory

Comment: java executable is at /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/bin

Comment: i updated the bash_profile like :  export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/bin:$CLASSPATH

Comment: what would be the exact line ? am sorry but am not getting it

Comment: Try `export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar`

Comment: export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar ... worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, the full path to the JAR file for the JDBC driver must be present in either the CLASSPATH or the JYTHONPATH environment variable so the Jython script can find it. These variables can be modified in several ways depending on the environment (shell) being used, as described in the Jata tutorial here:

[PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

In this particular case, simply adding the line

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar
```

to one of the startup files (e.g., ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile,  ~/.bashrc, ...) and then logging back in (or running `source` on the file) was the solution.