# Missing module to read MS Access using python

Tags: python-2.7, ms-access, odoo, jython, odoo-8

I was trying with the situation described in this question - [Read an Access database in Python on non-Windows platform (Linux or Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596737/read-an-access-database-in-python-on-non-windows-platform-linux-or-mac)

I downloaded the jython 2.5 jar file tried setting up the class path, but I am getting the error:

```
No module named com.ziclix.python.sql.
```

I dont know if i am doing it in a wrong way,
I just could not figure out how to configure odoo directory..

Comment: try launching jython on your terminal and then type import com.ziclix.python.sql and tell me if it works

Comment: can you give some more details, what are you trying to do? Are you configuring odoo-8? Which os are you using? because, i too don't have jython 2.5 and com.ziclix.python.sql in my system. I don't think they are useful for odoo-8.

Comment: I have scenario where I have to get data from MS Access database (which is on a remote server) and wanted to get those data into Odoo 8 through python code on Ubuntu, but in the above question link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596737/read-an-access-database-in-python-on-non-windows-platform-linux-or-mac, Gord Thompson referred me to jython and UCanaccess about which I have no knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Jython includes `com.ziclix.python.sql` in "jython.jar" itself, so no external dependencies should be required. If you are able to get Odoo to run under Jython (instead of CPython) then `com.ziclix.python.sql` should be available.