# Query for Access mdb can't be run in Python on Linux

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, odoo, mdbtools

I want to read a *.mdb database in odoo and import some data to odoo but I cannot read some fields.

In *.mdb I have 2 tables
first table is USERINFO with fields: SSN, Name, USERID
second table is CHECKINOUT with fields: USERID, CHECKTIME, CHECKTYPE

I use mdbtools and it runs well when I make this query

```
query1 = 'SELECT CHECKTIME,CHECKTYPE FROM CHECKINOUT'
```

The data I want is out.

But it errors when I run these two queries.

```
query2 = 'SELECT USERID,CHECKTIME FROM CHECKINOUT'
```

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

it's look the problem in in "USERID" field

and in the other query

```
query3 = """
SELECT c.CHECKTIME, c.CHECKTYPE, u.SSN, u.`Name`, u.USERID 
FROM CHECKINOUT c, USERINFO u  
WHERE c.USERID = u.USERID """
```

> Error at Line : syntax error near c.CHECKTIME syntax error near
>   c.CHECKTIME Got no result for 'SELECT c.CHECKTIME, c.CHECKTYPE, u.SSN
>   FROM CHECKINOUT c, USERINFO u WHERE c.USERID=u.USERID; ' command
>
> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', "[08001] Couldn't parse SQL\n (1)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)")

The query runs well in the DBeaver, but didn't running well in python.

Comment: Maybe this is caused by reserved words? Try to encapsulate specific fieldnames/tablenames in square brackets (`'SELECT [USERID], CHECKTIME FROM CHECKINOUT'`) to prevent such behaviour. Regarding your second query, shouldn't it be `query3 = "SELECT c.CHECKTIME, c.CHECKTYPE, u.SSN, u.Name, u.USERID 
FROM CHECKINOUT c, USERINFO u  
WHERE c.USERID = u.USERID"` (without the taking care of possibly reserved names)?

Comment: @UnhandledException I've tried your note. but nothing change.

Comment: You could try to rename field by field to a 'safe' name in the table (and in the query) to check out if any of them causes the trouble.

Comment: @UnhandledException the mdb files is from another aplication, so I think I cant change it as I please. that why I just want to select it and copy it to my db.

Comment: But for the purpose of finding the reason for error it could be done on a copy, or?

Comment: Any specific reason you need to use mdbtools and can't just use the Access database engine? This might just be a mdbtools bug

Comment: @UnhandledException yeah I will copy the mdb and rename it

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I use linux where I can't open Ms Access file directly. Right now I open the mdb with DBeaver.

Comment: I recommend JayDeBeApi + UCanAccess over mdbtools for Python and Linux, UCanAccess is a more mature and well-maintained afaik.

Comment: Further information re: suggestion from @ErikvonAsmuth can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614063/2144390).