# Connecting to MS Access with pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft Access database with `pyodbc` on Mac OS 10.12.6 with python version 3.6.4.

My code is the following:

```
conn_str = ('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'\
'DBQ=test.accdb;')

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

I receive an error while running the last line -

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I've double checked that my database is in the correct directory, and I've tried reinstalling pyodbc to make sure all of the libraries exist. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Good question I've been wondering this

Comment: what does your `odbcinst.ini` file look like, it can usually be found in the `/etc/` directory

Comment: I just searched for this file, and it doesn't appear to exist on my computer at all.

Comment: do `odbcinst -j` should tell you where they reside

Comment: It says the file is in the `/etc/` directory, but when I go to the `etc` directory and type in `cat obdcinst.ini`, I get a file not found error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with an Access database in Python on non-Windows platform (Linux or Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596737/working-with-an-access-database-in-python-on-non-windows-platform-linux-or-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` is Microsoft's ODBC driver for Access, and it is only available for Windows. If you want to work with Access databases directly from your Mac (i.e., without using a Windows virtual machine) then you'll either need to buy an Access ODBC driver for the Mac platform or consider one of the free options described here:

[Working with an Access database in Python on non-Windows platform (Linux or Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25596737/2144390)