# python script error in docker detached mode, but executes correctly in docker attached mode

Tags: java, docker, ucanaccess, jaydebeapi

I am using [JayDeBeAPI](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/) and [UCanAccess](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/) to extract data from MS Access `.mdb` files (as per [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614063/11727912)). My python script runs in docker debian container (`FROM python:3.9-slim`) and everything is OK if it runs in the "attached mode", but if I run the container in the "detached mode" and try to execute the script, I get this error:

```
jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: EXPORT in statement [SELECT * from export]"
...
```

How to make the script executing in the docker detached mode? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seemed to have fixed the problem was installing `sudo` in the docker image:

```
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
```

Strange, since I was executing `docker exec` as root already ... (?)